# is it correct to use php closing tag inside if statement? : <?php if (condition) { ?>}

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

In opencart 2.2 product.tpl file I found the following code which is quite confusing to me:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
<?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
<?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
<?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Specifically, I'm not able to understand how they can use ?> inside curly brackets of if statement? More important, I tried to revise the above code as following but then it stopped working:

```
<div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { 
$class = 'col-sm-6'; 
} 
elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { 
$class = 'col-sm-9'; 
} else { 
$class = 'col-sm-12'; 
?>
```

Any explanations?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, can you describe what did you get? did you get any error?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking? Yes the initial `if` is required, otherwise you'll get an error. As for the per line `<?php` and `?>`, it's down to the developer, and is valid either way.

Comment: my question is what is your problem with the above code?

Comment: I want to know syntax structure. As per my knowledge syntax should be <?php if(condition) { statement} ?>  but the code used is  <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    this is confusing to me.

Comment: Your question is not accurate because OpenCart doesn't actually do this: { ?>} there is always something inside the if statement curly braces.

Comment: @ Paul Feakins I double checked the code I pasted above is from product.tpl file and I've not touched it at all. They do use this code and the version I'm using is 2.2  for your information.

Comment: I'm talking about the question title.

Comment: _“I want to know syntax structure”_ - well then why don’t you go read up on it? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 1):

There is no mistake in the php code.

You can open and close a php tag as much as you like. During run time the files are processed and all the php code is interpreted each line at a time.

So it is fine to write like this

```php
<?php echo 'hello';
echo 'world';
?>
```

as well as this

```php
<?php echo 'hello'; ?>
<?php echo 'world'; ?>
```

The only reason why OpenCart uses the later style is becuase it is a bit nicer since the `<?php` tag creates a column and is a bit easier to read.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I got it that they are using opening and closing tag on per line basis. I'm okay with it. but I believe that if statement has the following structure : 

<?php if(condition) {statement} ?>

but in opencart I found everywhere the following structure:

<?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>

Why they are writing php closing tag without mentioning the statement that suppose to be executred?

Comment: The following code is copy pasted from product.tpl file. Can you explain it to me please?

<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>

Answer (score 0):

Its clearly visible, there is syntax error for `if`. You can't use `elseif` without `if`.

```
<?php 
if ($check) {
    // Code...
} elseif ($check_2) {
    // Code...
}
?>
```

Comment: Sir, the default template code is: <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>

Comment: I replaced it as:<div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { 
    $class = 'col-sm-6'; 
    } 
 elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { 
    $class = 'col-sm-9'; 
    } else { 
    $class = 'col-sm-12'; 
 ?>

Comment: after replacement the site stopped working, I'm not able to understand the default template file if statement syntax, but when I tried to replace it with the syntax I know about it stopped working.

Comment: You missed the closing '}' at last line. Use below code <div class="row"> <?php echo $column_left; ?> <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { $class = 'col-sm-6'; } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { $class = 'col-sm-9'; } else { $class = 'col-sm-12';} ?>

Comment: @ShrikantSaxena did this fix you issue, if yes, please up vote. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { 
$class = 'col-sm-6'; 
} 
elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { 
$class = 'col-sm-9'; 
} else { 
$class = 'col-sm-12'; 
} // this is missing in your case
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>

<?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { 
         $class = 'col-sm-6'; 
       } 
      elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { 
         $class = 'col-sm-9'; 
       } else { 
         $class = 'col-sm-12'; 
       } // you have missed this "}" for the else .
 ?>
```